# $\Bbb E[X] = \infty$. Show unique existence of $\mathcal F$-measurable $Y$, with $\int_A X \mathrm dP = \int_A Y \mathrm dP, \forall A \in \mathcal F$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let $X\ge 0$ be a random variable with $\Bbb E[X] = \infty$. I have to show that there exists a unique $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable $0\le Y \le \infty$, so that $$\int_A X \mathrm dP = \int_A Y \mathrm dP,\:\: \forall A \in \mathcal F$$
$\mathcal F$ isn't further specified.

I don't really know where to start for showing this. Does anyone have any hints or tips on how to show this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, it's of course $\ge$, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time, so I can only give a sketch of proof.

Existence: For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $X_{n}=\min(X,n)$.
Let $Y_{n}=E[X_{n}\mid\mathcal{F}]$. Let $Y=\limsup_{n}Y_{n}$.

Uniqueness: Suppose that $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ have that property.
Let $A=[Y_{1}<Y_{2}<\infty]$. We assert that $P(A)=0$. Define $A_{n}=[\frac{1}{n}\leq Y_{2}-Y_{1}\leq n]$.
Note that $A=\cup_{n}A_{n}$. Therefore, it suffices to show that
$P(A_{n})=0$.
Define $B=[Y_1<Y_2=\infty]$. By considering $B_n=[Y_1\leq n]\cap[Y_=\infty]$ and note that $B=\cup_n B_n$, we can show that $P(B)=0$. Therefore $P([Y_1<Y_2])=0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try to work it out.

Comment: @ DeltaChief. I fix my proof a little bit.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in depth why you chose $X_n$ in such a fashio an why you need it in the first place. Wouldn't just using $Y = E[X\mid\mathcal{F}]$ suffice. And why did you show that the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are equal. Wouldn't you need to show that if I have two different $Y$ that they are unique?

Comment: 1. I tried to confine myself not using anything beyond the standard setting for conditional expectation $E[X\mid\mathcal{F}]$, where we require that $X$ is integrable.
We try to extend the results for general non-negative measurable random variables.

2. The $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in the uniqueness part is not the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in existence part.
May be we can replace them by $Y$ and $Y'$ respectively.

Comment: Note that such $Y$ is unique up to a set of measure zero.